# PHP String Contains A Substring

Tags: php, substring, performance

I hold two list of words, let's say listA and listB.
I want to check for every word in listB if it's contained in listA. 
The intuitive way is to go for each word in listB and check :

```
$pos = strpos($word , $listBContent) ; 
if( $pos != false) { ... }
```

But i'm afraid this kind of process is too "expensive" - let's assume listA and listB contains n words each, the complexity will be O(n^2).
Is there any method which I can use in order to run this certain process more efficiently ?
I thought of using a suffix tree,  but I ain't got a clue if it's possible (and how to) create one from a list of words  , and not from a single word.
Any suggestion will be helpful ,
thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but in case of your code you need to use `!==`, otherwise if `$pos` is 0 it would evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Altough it's not the point , you're right !

Comment: @Itamar: How does you list look like? ever heard of arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function called [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Do you have any idea how efficient is this function in comparison to the method I've brought ?

Comment: I am sorry I haven't really tested it in terms of efficiency. But this is built-in method so it wouldn't be so bad right? :)

Comment: @Itamar: You can easily make the check yourself by calling `microtime()` before and after each function, and subtracting them. That will give you the time it took to perform each one.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as answer so other people can also benefit from it. Thanks.